# How to find my possibly lost partition?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, data-recovery

I couldn't open my computer using Windows 7 operating system and I didn't have my files backed up, so I opened it using ubuntu,stored in a usb stick, without installing. I(a friend of mine, I am just a noob) created a partition that used to contain all my files, with the name "161 GB Volume"(my hd capacity is 1TB).

Once I accidentally started the installation of Ubuntu, but not in the "161.. " area. When I realised it, I just pulled the usb stick out of the PC (yes,this was a reeeeally bad option). Now I can still open Ubuntu as before, but I can't see my files. Plus,I can find the Gparted Partition Editor, but can not open it (it crashes or so). I tried to find my files again using this [Access Windows Files in Ubuntu](http://www.wikihow.com/Access-Windows-Files-in-Ubuntu)
guide, but all I got was a message that it was exclusively opened by another device or system or that it was already mounted.

Typing the command `sudo fdisk -l` on the terminal, I can see these:

```
Device Boot     Start      End       Blocks     Id     System
/dev/sda1 *       2048     314574847  157286400    7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT 
/dev/sda2      1942253568 1953517567   5632000    27  Hidden NTFS WinRE 
/dev/sda3      314574848  1942253567  813839360   83   Linux 

Partition table entries are not in disk order 

Disk /dev/sdb: 2013 MB, 2013265920 bytes

 Device Boot    Start    End     Blocks   Id    System
/dev/sdb1 *      32    3932159   1966064   b  W95 FAT32
```

Is there anything that I can do to see my files?

Comment: It's a little difficult to understand. Can you see the 161GB Volume in the file browser? In any case, don't panic. We have good tools for data recovery – as long as you stop using the disk in question and particularly don't write a lot of data to it. That will overwrite your lost data.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.No,I can not see the 161GB Volume anywhere. :(

Comment: Run the "Disks" application from within Ubuntu and see if you see if there. It might simply not be mounted.

Answer (score 0):

When you paniced and unplugged the USB while running, you might have corrupted it. maybe you should consider to get a new ubuntu-USB stick? or use a live CD.

in any event, when you have a working live USB/CD, you should be able to restart the pc, and boot from CD/USB, and your disk should appear as a drive that can be mounted.

when you have done this, maye you can give us some more details on the errors you see, it is a bit hard to help with this information.

Comment: Thank you!I can still boot from the usb.Typing the command sudo fdisk -l on the terminal,I can see these:Device Boot      Start        End     Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   314574847   157286400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2      1942253568  1953517567     5632000   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda3       314574848  1942253567   813839360   83  Linux
Partition table entries are not in disk order                 Disk /dev/sdb: 2013 MB, 2013265920 bytes
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          32     3932159     1966064    b  W95 FAT32

Comment: But I have no idea what they mean and what I can do with them.

Comment: @user264432: please edit your question instead. Among other things, it will make it much easier to read.